# Trying to Run fltk but would get undefined error

Tags: compiling, c++, make

I am trying to compile a old programming assignment and when using my schools server it compiles without error and still works now. I am trying to compile on my home computer but would give me this error when I make:

```
g++      -std=c++11        -c -o Graph.o Graph.cpp
g++      -std=c++11        -c -o GUI.o GUI.cpp
g++      -std=c++11        -c -o Simple_window.o Simple_window.cpp
g++      -std=c++11        -c -o Window.o Window.cpp
g++      -std=c++11        -lfltk -lfltk_images  sample_main4.cpp Graph.o GUI.o Simple_window.o Window.o

/tmp/ccshmUhR.o: In function `Graph_lib::Window::~Window()':
sample_main4.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib6WindowD2Ev[_ZN9Graph_lib6WindowD5Ev]+0x31): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()'
/tmp/ccshmUhR.o:(.rodata._ZTV13Simple_window[_ZTV13Simple_window]+0x28): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::handle(int)'
/tmp/ccshmUhR.o:(.rodata._ZTV13Simple_window[_ZTV13Simple_window]+0x30): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::resize(int, int, int, int)'
/tmp/ccshmUhR.o:(.rodata._ZTV13Simple_window[_ZTV13Simple_window]+0x38): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::show()'
/tmp/ccshmUhR.o:(.rodata._ZTV13Simple_window[_ZTV13Simple_window]+0x40): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::hide()'
/tmp/ccshmUhR.o:(.rodata._ZTV13Simple_window[_ZTV13Simple_window]+0x60): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::flush()'
Graph.o: In function `Graph_lib::draw_mark(Point, char)':
Graph.cpp:(.text+0xb9e): undefined reference to `fl_draw(char const*, int, int)'
Graph.o: In function `Graph_lib::Text::draw_lines() const':
Graph.cpp:(.text+0x1223): undefined reference to `fl_draw(char const*, int, int)'
Graph.o: In function `Graph_lib::Image::Image(Point, String, Graph_lib::Suffix::Encoding)':
Graph.cpp:(.text+0x1dbc): undefined reference to `Fl_JPEG_Image::Fl_JPEG_Image(char const*)'
Graph.cpp:(.text+0x1df6): undefined reference to `Fl_GIF_Image::Fl_GIF_Image(char const*)'
Graph.o: In function `Fl_Image::Fl_Image(int, int, int)':
Graph.cpp:(.text._ZN8Fl_ImageC2Eiii[_ZN8Fl_ImageC5Eiii]+0x12): undefined reference to `vtable for Fl_Image'
Graph.o: In function `fl_color(unsigned int)':
Graph.cpp:(.text._Z8fl_colorj[_Z8fl_colorj]+0xe): undefined reference to `fl_graphics_driver'
Graph.cpp:(.text._Z8fl_colorj[_Z8fl_colorj]+0x21): undefined reference to `fl_graphics_driver'
Graph.o: In function `fl_color()':
Graph.cpp:(.text._Z8fl_colorv[_Z8fl_colorv]+0x7): undefined reference to `fl_graphics_driver'
Graph.o: In function `fl_line_style(int, int, char*)':
Graph.cpp:(.text._Z13fl_line_styleiiPc[_Z13fl_line_styleiiPc]+0x15): undefined reference to `fl_graphics_driver'
Graph.cpp:(.text._Z13fl_line_styleiiPc[_Z13fl_line_styleiiPc]+0x26): undefined reference to `fl_graphics_driver'
Graph.o:Graph.cpp:(.text._Z7fl_rectiiii[_Z7fl_rectiiii]+0x17): more undefined references to `fl_graphics_driver' follow
Graph.o: In function `Graph_lib::Bad_image::draw(int, int, int, int, int, int)':
Graph.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib9Bad_image4drawEiiiiii[_ZN9Graph_lib9Bad_image4drawEiiiiii]+0x2d): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::draw_empty(int, int)'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x20): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::copy(int, int)'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x28): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::color_average(unsigned int, float)'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x30): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::desaturate()'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x38): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::label(Fl_Widget*)'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x40): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::label(Fl_Menu_Item*)'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::uncache()'
Graph.o: In function `Graph_lib::Bad_image::~Bad_image()':
Graph.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageD2Ev[_ZN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `Fl_Image::~Fl_Image()'
Graph.o:(.rodata._ZTIN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE[_ZTIN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Fl_Image'
GUI.o: In function `Graph_lib::Button::attach(Graph_lib::Window&)':
GUI.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `Fl_Button::Fl_Button(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
GUI.o: In function `Graph_lib::In_box::attach(Graph_lib::Window&)':
GUI.cpp:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `Fl_Input::Fl_Input(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
GUI.o: In function `Graph_lib::Out_box::put(String const&)':
GUI.cpp:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `Fl_Input_::value(char const*)'
GUI.o: In function `Graph_lib::Out_box::attach(Graph_lib::Window&)':
GUI.cpp:(.text+0x291): undefined reference to `Fl_Output::Fl_Output(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
Simple_window.o: In function `Simple_window::wait_for_button()':
Simple_window.cpp:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `Fl::wait()'
Simple_window.cpp:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `Fl::redraw()'
Window.o: In function `Graph_lib::Window::Window(int, int, String const&)':
Window.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int, int, char const*)'
Window.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()'
Window.o: In function `Graph_lib::Window::Window(Point, int, int, String const&)':
Window.cpp:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
Window.cpp:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()'
Window.o: In function `Graph_lib::Window::draw()':
Window.cpp:(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::draw()'
Window.o: In function `Graph_lib::Window::attach(Graph_lib::Widget&)':
Window.cpp:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `Fl_Group::begin()'
Window.cpp:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `Fl_Group::end()'
Window.o: In function `Graph_lib::gui_main()':
Window.cpp:(.text+0x47b): undefined reference to `Fl::run()'
Window.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x28): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::handle(int)'
Window.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x30): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::resize(int, int, int, int)'
Window.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x38): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::show()'
Window.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x40): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::hide()'
Window.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE[_ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x60): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::flush()'
Window.o:(.rodata._ZTIN9Graph_lib6WindowE[_ZTIN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Fl_Window'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:25: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

This is my make file:

```
CC     = g++     # the c compiler to use
DFLAGS = -std=c++11       # common defines
FLTK   = -lfltk -lfltk_images   # fltk defines

all: main

clean:
        rm -f *.o

# ==== FLTK LIBRARY ====
Graph.o: Graph.cpp
        $(CC) $(DFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

GUI.o: GUI.cpp
        $(CC) $(DFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Simple_window.o: Simple_window.cpp
        $(CC) $(DFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Window.o: Window.cpp
        $(CC) $(DFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

# ==== MAIN FILE ====
main: Graph.o GUI.o Simple_window.o Window.o
        $(CC) $(DFLAGS) $(FLTK) sample_main4.cpp Graph.o GUI.o 
Simple_window.o Window.o
```

It should compile but I dont know what I am missing in my ubuntu since it works on my school server, but not mine. All files are in the exact place on both servers.

Comment: I'd suspect the libraries `-lfltk -lfltk_images` need to go AFTER the other objects (making the link order L to R)

Comment: i.e. `$(CC) $(DFLAGS) sample_main4.cpp Graph.o GUI.o  $(FLTK)`

Comment: Doing this method:                                  
$(CC) $(DFLAGS) sample_main4.cpp Graph.o GUI.o 
Simple_window.o Window.o $(FLTK)                                            
Gives this error:                                    
Graph.o: In function `Graph_lib::Bad_images(int, int )`:                                          Graph.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib9Bad_imageC2Eii.....) : undefined reference to `Fl_Image::Fl_image(int, int, int)                              collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:25: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: What is  your school computer? And home one? I don't want Manufactures and Models but operating systems (with versions). Debugging a problem between two Ubuntu machines is probably less of an issue than say Ununtu 14.04 and Windows 10. To close voters we may not be the best site for coding issuesbut it is not off topic.